# how many different letter configurations of length 4 or 5 can be formed using the letters of the word achieve?

Tags: combinatorics

The answer the textbook is looking for is 1800 but I can't get there. I think I might not understand exactly what the question is asking.

Comment: The question is asking you to count all the permutations that can be formed by arranging either $4$ or $5$ letters taken from the word ACHIEVE.  Consider cases, depending on the length of the string and the number of Es which appear.

Comment: So for configurations with length 4, you have the amount of configurations with 0 E's, amount with 1 E, and emount with 2 E's divided by two. But that's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Let's first look at the letter configurations without two "e"s. In this case, the question is equivalent to:

*"How many different letter configurations of length 4 or 5 can be formed using the letters of the word "achiev"?"*

For lc (letter configurations) with length $4$, we should choose $4$ letters and arrange them. The number of ways to do this is ${{6}\choose{4}} \cdot 4! = 15\cdot24 = 360$

Repeating the same with lcs of length $5$, we get ${{6}\choose{5}} \cdot 5! = 6\cdot120 = 720$

The total is $720+360 = 1080$ (1)

Now  let's look at the lcs that contain two "e"s. Two of the letters are already chosen, and now we have to choose $2$ and $3$ letters from "a,c,h,i,v" in order to form lcs of length $4$ and $5$, respectively.

For lcs of length $4$ we get ${5\choose2}\cdot\frac{4!}{2!} = 120$

The $2!$ appeared in the denominator because there are two identical letters.

For lcs of length $5$ we get ${5\choose3}\cdot\frac{5!}{2!} = 600$

Summing these up, we get $600+120 = 720$ (2)

Summing answers (1) and (2), we get $1080 + 720 = 1800$

Comment: Please do not answer questions which do not meet [quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards).

Comment: OK awesome thank you. I think that what was tripping me up was multiplying 6 choose 5 by 5!. So the logic is that 6 choose 4 is a combination and then you multiply it by the number of ways to permute that many letters.

Answer (score 0):

Such questions where all the letters of a word are not to be used can conveniently be solved using generating functions.

We expand $(x^0+x^1)^5(x^0+x^1+x^2/2!)$ and compute $4!*$ (coefficient of $x^4) + 5!$* (coefficient of $x^5$), which yields

$4!*20 + 5!*11 = 1800$

---

To explain a bit, $(x^0+x^1)^5$ represents five unique letters which may occur $0$ or $1$ time and  $(x^0 + x^1 +x^2/2!)$ represents the $E's$ which may occur $0,1 \;or\; 2$ times in the word. Note that $x^2$ has been divided by $2!$ to take care of the same letter repeating twice.